# jquery media conflict with swfobject

Tags: jquery, media, swfobject

If I use jquery media plugin WITH swfobject 2.2 I get an 'unknown runtime error' in IE.

It works fine in FF and other browsers.

If i remove swfobject.js then the media works fine as it loads using simple object/embed tags.

But I need to use swfobject as well (for other things).

Has anybody come across this or a fix?

A.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set **id** attribute to the element with your video.

```
<a class="media" href="video.flv" id="specimen_video">Specimen Video</a>
```

I had similar problem and it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery no conflict.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
jQuery("div p").hide();
// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```